# HOW do you Redirect buddypress login to EDIT tab not PROFILE tab on profile page?

Tags: redirect, login, buddypress

HOW do you Redirect buddypress login to EDIT tab not PROFILE tab on profile page?

Comment: cant get anything to work for this task:

Comment: function my_login_redirect( $user_id, $user_login, $user_password, $user_email, $usermeta ) {
    wp_redirect( bp_loggedin_user_domain() . '/profile/edit/group/1/' );
    exit();
}
add_action( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 5 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try...

```
function admin_default_page() {
    global $user;
    return bp_core_get_user_domain( $user->ID ).'/groups/';
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

Or a plugin... [BuddyPress Login Redirect to Profile](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-redirect-to-profile/)

Comment: this works like a charm ^^ THANK YOU!!! BIG TIME!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

function admin_default_page() {
    global $user;
    return bp_core_get_user_domain( $user->ID ).'/profile/edit/group/2/';
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');